# Are the Winter Bash hats drawing data from last year?

Tags: bug

A little while back, the Winter Bash icon appeared on the top bar, along with the notifications:  "You earned Glasses With A Number On Top on Science Fiction & Fantasy!"

However, the description for this hat is:  "post a message in chat within ±12 hours of the UTC New Year’s begin that gets starred," which I obviously haven't done *this* season.  I see my avatar as wearing the hat, but does everyone else?  Moreover, is this a site-wide glitch or is it specific to Science Fiction and Fantasy?  (I am not getting erroneous hats on any other Stack Exchange sites.)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339893/winter-bash-2019-bugs-with-the-glasses-with-a-number-on-top-hat-and-the-phila